# Why the DirectoryModuleCatalog loads wrong Module?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

i use Prism 6.3.0 and Unity DI for my WPF App. The Main Application and module was created through the Template Extension for Visual Studio and the Bootstrapper was changed to use the DirectoryModuleCatalog.

**Bootstrapper:**

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        DirectoryModuleCatalog catalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
        return catalog;

    }
}
```

**My Module:**

```
public class Module1Module : IModule
{
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public Module1Module(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager, ILoggerFacade logger)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>();
        _logger.Log("BBC",Category.Debug,Priority.High);
    }
}
```

When I compile the Main Application and the Module, then the module is loaded from the specified Modulepath.

**Problem:**

When I make a copy of the compiled Module (Assembly/DLL) located in the ModulePath to the MainApplicationdirectory, make changes to the module code like this below, compile the module and copy the new compiled files to the specified Modulepath (.\Modules), then I see in the Log "BBC", means the Module from the MainApplicationdirectory is loaded and not from the ModulesPath.

```
public class Module1Module : IModule
{
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public Module1Module(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager, ILoggerFacade logger)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>();
        _logger.Log("123",Category.Debug,Priority.High);
    }
}
```

**Expected Result:**

The directorymodulecatalog shall use the specified path to load the module and not from the MainApplicationpath.

**Question:**

How could I fix this and is this the correct behavouir?

Comment: Do you reference the module (-project) from the application (-project)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, if I understood your question correct. I created both projects MainApp and Module through the Template Pack in one Visual Studio Solution, but I did not created a Reference between Mainapplication and Module, because this makes no sense. I'm able to reproduce my problem on different Computers.The same Reference what both Programs have is PrismLib from Nuget package.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. On my machine, the `DirectoryModuleCatalog` ignores modules outside the given directory. Check your references whether anyone references the module, causing its assembly to be loaded independent of the module catalog.

Comment: I will search for possibility to upload my solution to the internet, but upload of images or files are not allowed from my employeer, means i have to do it in some hours.

Comment: Did you checked with Release or Debug? I checked only Debug build

Comment: I have to create small youtube video to describe the issue. Will take some time.